# sphinxでPDFを作成するときに分割したい

Tags: sphinx

Sphinx1.8.2でアプリのマニュアルを作成しています。
1～10章までありますが、HTMLへは全章を、
PDFは2分割して、1～7章を「基本編」として、8～10章を「応用編」として、出力したいのです。

また、この時のtitleもそれぞれ「基本編」「応用編」として別々にしたいと思っています。

このような場合の設定方法をご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

現在のところ、以下の方法で自己解決しています。

1. toctreeを持つ.rstを2つ作成する

   - 基本編用： source/index_latex1.rst
   - 応用編用： source/index_latex2.rst
2. source/conf_latex1 にconf.pyを作成し、`master_doc = 'index_latex1'`
3. source/conf_latex2 にconf.pyを作成し、`master_doc = 'index_latex2'`
4. 基本編のビルドを以下で実行

   > sphinx-build -a -b latex -c source/conf_latex1 source build/latex_basic
   >   ./build/latex_basic/make
5. 同様に応用編のビルドを以下で実行

   > sphinx-build -a -b latex -c source/conf_latex2 source　build/latex_advance
   >   ./build/latex_advance/make

ただ、この状態だと、コンテンツの順番が変わったり、リリース番号が変わったときには、HTML用とlatex用×2の設定を変更しなければならず、ベストな方法とは思えません。
他に良い方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、アドバイスをお願いいたします。